# How to open ListPreference immediately when activity is created?

Tags: android, android-preferences, listpreference

I have an application with two screens, MainActivity - screen with buttons, and SecondActivity - settings screen. In this SecondActivity I have one ListPreference.

How to open this ListPreference when SecondActivity is opening?

Answer (score 0):

You first need to calculate the **position** of `ListPreference` in your `PreferenceScreen`. Then try this code:

```
PreferenceScreen main = (PreferenceScreen)findPreference(getString(R.string.pref_screen_root));
    main.onItemClick(null, null, pos, 0);
```

Here **pos** is the ***position*** of `ListPreference` in `PreferenceScreen`.
`R.string.pref_screen_root` is the key of your `PreferenceScreen`.

Here is the simplest xml file of:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:key="@string/pref_screen_root" >
 <ListPreference
            android:defaultValue="0"
            android:entries="@array/list_entries"
            android:entryValues="@array/list_values"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_earth"
            android:key="@string/pref_country"
            android:title="Select a country" />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Comment: How to set this key: R.string.pref_screen_root?

Comment: @ТОР, thank you, But how to do that only when button in MainActivity is clicked?

Comment: @ОлегМедведев When you click button of MainActivity, you call Second Activity. On method OnCreate of Second Activity, you will inflate your PreferenceScreen. And run above code after inflating the PreferenceScreen.

Comment: @ТОР, You misunderstood me. How to do this only if the button is pressed IN THE MainActivity? I also have ThirdActivity with the list menu. And there is a Settings item. When I click there, I go to SecondActivity. But if I do that, I don't want to open ListPreferences in MainActivity.